# Python - While Loops Not Appearing in Console When the code is run

Tags: python, function, while-loop

I'm currently trying to make a scoring system where a user can enter an event as a team and I used while loops and defs to make this possible but I'm having trouble using them.

```
def team_menu():

 global teamS

 team_player = ""

 while team_player:
  team_player = input("What is your name:")
  print("""\n Available Teams \n
  1) Team Ahab
  2) Team Ishmael
\n 3) Go back to Main Menu\n""")

  team_choice = ""
  team_choice_option = ["1","2","3"] # all valid choices on team menu

 while team_choice not in team_choice_option:
  team_choice = input("Enter your choice here:")

 if team_choice == "1":
  teamS["Team 1"]["Team Ahab"].append(team_player)
  print(teamS["Team 1"])
  print("Thank You for Joining Team Ahab")
  team_choice = True

 elif team_choice == "2":
  teamS["Team "+ 2]["Team Miller"].append(team_player)
  print(teamS["Team 2"])
  print("\nThank You for Joining Team Miller\n")
  team_choice = True

 elif team_choice == "3":
  menu()
  team_choice = True

 else:
  print("Enter a value between 1-3")
  team_choice = False
```

When I try to run this code it imidiently asks me for what to team to join even though it didn't even ask of the name of the user before. How do I fix this? My ideal output would be to ask for the name of the user first then let them pick what team they want to join

Comment: `team_player` is `""`. As a boolean, `""` evaluates to `False`, so `while team_player:` is `while "":` which is `while False:` so the `while` loop does not run at all.

Comment: _Please_ don't use single space indentation. it is incredibly hard to read, and in a language like Python where whitespace is significant it's completely insane.

Comment: Why is that? I tried removing the spaces but it looks confusing to read to me. I'm a beginner so please undestand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loops within the function seem unnecessary since you're only prompting for one player.

```
from typing import Dict, List, NamedTuple


class Team(NamedTuple):
    name: str
    players: List[str]


def team_menu(team_dict: Dict[str, Team]) -> None:
    player = input("What is your name: ")
    print(
        """
        Available Teams
        1) Team Ahab
        2) Team Ishmael
        3) Go back to Main Menu
        """
    )
    choice = ""
    while choice not in ["1", "2", "3"]:
        choice = input("Enter your choice here:")
    if choice == "3":
        return  # back to main menu

    team_dict[choice].players.append(player)
    print(f"Thank you for joining {team_dict[choice].name}")


team_dict = {
    "1": Team("Team Ahab", []),
    "2": Team("Team Ishmael", []),
}

team_menu(team_dict)
# menu()
```

Comment: Thanks for this reaally apprrciate it. Hey one question what does ```
def team_menu(team_dict: Dict[str, Team]) -> None:``` do exactly? I'm quite new to python so please explain it using simple terms as possible other than that thanks for the help!

Comment: It starts defining a function called `team_menu` that takes a single argument called `team_dict` (which is a dictionary of `Team` objects keyed by `str`) and returns `None`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change 7th line:

```py
while team_player == "":
```

You are using complex two-state branching based on team_player and team_choice values, it could be facilitated with one current state of team menu aka [state machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine):

```py
from collections import namedtuple


def team_menu():

    # Code smells, it could be passed here by param, i.e. team_menu(teamS)
    global teamS

    states = namedtuple("States", ("CHOOSE_PLAYER", "CHOOSE_TEAM", "END"))
    # Starts from player.
    state = states.CHOOSE_PLAYER

    while state != states.END:
        if state == states.CHOOSE_PLAYER:
            team_player = input("What is your name:")

            # If player name selected then continue with team.
            if team_player:
                state = states.CHOOSE_TEAM

        elif state == states.CHOOSE_TEAM:
            print(
                """
Available Teams

1) Team Ahab
2) Team Ishmael
3) Go back to Main Menu
"""
            )
            team_choice = input("Enter your choice here:")
            # all valid choices on team menu
            team_choice_option = ["1", "2", "3"]

            # If team selected, add this player and continue with another player.
            if team_choice in team_choice_option:
                state = states.CHOOSE_PLAYER

                if team_choice == "1":
                    teamS["Team 1"]["Team Ahab"].append(team_player)
                    print(teamS["Team 1"])
                    print("Thank You for Joining Team Ahab")

                elif team_choice == "2":
                    teamS["Team 2"]["Team Miller"].append(team_player)
                    print(teamS["Team 2"])
                    print("Thank You for Joining Team Miller")

                elif team_choice == "3":
                    # You don't need to call menu() but if you do, then
                    # be prepared to get sometimes "RecursionError: maximum
                    # recursion depth exceeded".
                    state = states.END

            else:
                print("Enter a value between 1-3")

    # There is the end of team_menu() it could return `teamS` here
    # to main `menu()` to avoid using global.
    return None
```

Comment: Sorry, the quick answer led me to mistake, while loop works when it has True statement. Check @Kraigolas answer. And you are using complex two-state branching based on team_player and team_choice values that could be facilitated and refactored with one current state of team menu that switches between all available states.